# Is Walk Navigation possible in orthographic mode?

Tags: navigation, orthographic

When I’m in orthographic mode and click *Walk Navigation*, the view changes to perspective, is it possible to fix this? So that I always stay in orthographic mode? Are there addons that support this implementation? What I need most is the functionality to rotate up, down, left, right using the mouse cursor, like in *Walk Navigation*.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: One thing you could do is create an orthographic camera, optionally snap it to current view, adopt the camera view, lock camera to view, and then enable walk.  You continue looking through the ortho camera, which locks to the walking orientation.

Comment: You can orbit around objects on Orthographic view mode, but moving forward and backwards has no effect except objects disappearing when outside the camera limits.

Comment: @Nathan It worked! Thank you! There is a problem, if you use mouse scroll, the zoom occurs not only inside the camera, but also outside. Thus, the rectangle of the camera view itself changes in scale. How to fix it?

Comment: Not totally sure I get you.  The camera box ("passepartout") changes size because you're *zooming* your view not moving.  (And since you're in ortho view, moving wouldn't do anything anyways.)  If you don't want to see the box, disable it in properties/camera(data)/viewport display.

Comment: @Nathan Apparently I was doing something wrong. Now everything is fine! Thanks again